# Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'sc' (in VS2012)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sitecore, tagprefix

I can't get Visual Studio 2012 to recognize the 'sc' tagPrefix.
My web.config contains the usual line:

```
<add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls"
     assembly="Sitecore.Kernel"/>
```

But I keep getting the `Unrecognized tag prefix or device filter 'sc'` message when I try to add a `<sc />` tag to my page or user control.

If I open the same solution in Visual Studio 2010, it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: In installing VS2012 did you install .NET 4.5? What version of SC are you running and does it support .NET 4.5?

Comment: I would say you probably have a warning/error in your Web.config file. Have you checked your Output window to see if there are any warnings?

Comment: Do you have a website or a web app in your project structure?

Comment: @Simon: VS 2012 comes with 4.5

Comment: Simon: yes, 4.5 is installed, the project uses 4.0 though... 
Tom: it shows me loads of errors, but that also happens in VS2010 (exact same amount) and it is all related to sitecore config nodes... 
Mark: it's a web application project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found it.
The Web.Config that is provided by Sitecore contains the following section:

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Analytics" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

For VS2012, you need to remove the **asp** tagprefixes, so the section ends up being:

```
<pages validateRequest="false">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Analytics" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

No idea why, but that solved the problem for me!

Little side note though: after this change, it won't work in VS2010 anymore.. (neither `<sc: />` nor `<asp: />`)

Comment: This is crazy with the SC. I am having the same trouble but I dont see any <pages validateRequest in my web.config file. It works in 2010 but not in 2012. Not even it recognize <asp: tags too.

Comment: If you don't have the <pages> element at all in your web.config, try adding it (copy the 2nd example from my answer) in the <system.web> section

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed .net 4.5 it overrides the 4.0 and you would have other issues (depending on the specific sitecore version that you are running on...)

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works in VS2010 and not in VS2012 (same solution, same computer) -- The only problem .NET 4.5 will cause is something with the membershipprovider which can easily be worked around by changing a setting.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the below tag on top of the aspx file.**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

**Add below tags in web.config file**

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
    </controls>
</pages>
```

On the Tools menu, click Choose Toolbox Items. Add AjaxControlToolkit.dll files if you don't have them. Click Browse, then an Open dialog box appears. In the My Places Bar, select My Computer to browse for items installed on your computer.